# Automatic propagation of private field javadoc's to getters/setters?

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I've documented my bean private fields with Javadoc, explaining what each field is for. Can i propagate these documentations somehow to corrseponding getters/setters to reduce duplications  of documentation? Is there's some kind of Javadoc macro for this at least?

Comment: Not sure, but I would just JavaDoc the getters and setters as they are part of the public API.

Comment: ... In fact I would only Javadoc methods which are part of the API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could link the javadoc comment of getters and setters to the private field by adding a javadoc link:

```
{@link Class#field}
```

However i would not really recommend this. As the previous commentators stated, i would just document the getters and setters properly. Javadoc documents your public API, which the getters and setters may belong to. Your private fields do not belong to the public API.

Comment: Maybe the other way around: add an link from the fields to the getter/setter, so whoever looks at the documentation with `-private` can jump to the description.

Comment: but then where put the description? on getter, on setter or both?

Answer (score 0):

You may consider some compile-time tools like Lombok:

http://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter.html